# How can I add Full-Tab Color to Google Sheet?

Tags: css, google-sheets, userscripts

I'm just starting to get the hang of google apps scripts and found a script that colors the whole tab rather than the thin line underneath. I copy/pasted the code into a new script file, hit save, and refreshed the sheet but it did not change the tab appearance. How can I add this script to an existing sheet and apply it to all tabs?

Code is available as both userscript and CSS at https://userstyles.org/styles/110436

Thank you!

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name          Full-Color Tabs for Google Sheets/Spreadsheets
// @namespace     http://userstyles.org
// @description   Google's new Sheets allows you to change the tab colors, but the color is just a narrow stripeâ€”not enough of a visual cue to immediately identify tabs by their color. This stylesheet causes your selected colors to fill the whole tab, similar to the way Excel does it. It also includes optional increased rounding of the bottom corners of each tab to further help distinguish one tab from the next. The rounding styles can be deleted. 3/23/15 update makes the active tab title bold, making it easier to confirm which tab is active. These styles can be deleted.
// @author        Bunnyslippers
// @homepage      https://userstyles.org/styles/110436
// @include       http://docs.google.com/spreadsheets*
// @include       https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets*
// @run-at        document-start
// @version       0.20150323072833
// ==/UserScript==

(function() {var css = [
    ".docs-sheet-tab-color {",
    "  height: 31px;",
    "  margin: -23px -20px 0 -5px;",
    "  position: relative;",
    "  z-index: -1;",
    "}",
    "",
    "/* Optional rounded bottom tab corners. Corners can be made more or less round by increasing or decreasing the last two values (10px). Delete the rule entirely to use Google\'s default 2px radius */",
    "",
    ".docs-sheet-tab, .docs-sheet-tab-color {",
    "  border-radius: 0 0 10px 10px",
    "}",
    "",
    "/* Optional: Darken tab borders. This style can be deleted. */",
    ".docs-sheet-tab {",
    "  border-color: rgb(164, 164, 164);",
    "  border-top-color: rgb(170, 170, 170);",
    "  }",
    "",
    "",
    "/* Optional: Make active tab title bold for easy identification. This style can be deleted. */",
    ".docs-sheet-active-tab {",
    "    font-weight: 700 !important;",
    "  }"
].join("\n");
if (typeof GM_addStyle != "undefined") {
    GM_addStyle(css);
} else if (typeof PRO_addStyle != "undefined") {
    PRO_addStyle(css);
} else if (typeof addStyle != "undefined") {
    addStyle(css);
} else {
    var node = document.createElement("style");
    node.type = "text/css";
    node.appendChild(document.createTextNode(css));
    var heads = document.getElementsByTagName("head");
    if (heads.length > 0) {
        heads[0].appendChild(node);
    } else {
        // no head yet, stick it whereever
        document.documentElement.appendChild(node);
    }
}
})();
```

Comment: This code is for the browser extension Stylish, not for appscript. You need to install it and it applies if the url starts with "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets".

Comment: Actually, the code in this question is a Tampermonkey script.  Install [Tampermonkey](https://www.tampermonkey.net/?ext=dhdg&browser=chrome) and then revisit that userstyles.org page and hit the "Install style as userscript " link.

Comment: I installed the Tampermonkey extension and installed the userscript. Unfortunately it's still not working. Gave me a "not defined" error for 'PRO_addStyle' and 'addStyle'. Could that be the cause?

Comment: Doubtful.  You got the error in Tampermonkey's editor and not in the browser console, right?

Comment: Correct, the script is enabled and active but no changes in the google sheet

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to add `@grant    GM_addStyle` in the header:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         Google Shets
// @include      https://*docs.google.*/spreadsheets/*
// for change CSS
// @grant    GM_addStyle       
// ==/UserScript==


GM_addStyle(`


    .docs-sheet-tab-color {
          height: 31px  !important;
          margin: -23px -20px 0 -5px  !important;
          position: relative  !important;
          z-index: -1  !important;
        }

    /* Optional rounded bottom tab corners. Corners can be made more or less round by increasing or decreasing the last two values (10px). Delete the rule entirely to use Google\'s default 2px radius */

    .docs-sheet-tab .docs-sheet-tab-color {
          border-radius: 0 0 10px 10px  !important;
        }

    /* Optional: Darken tab borders. This style can be deleted. */
    .docs-sheet-tab {
          border-color: rgb(164 164 164)  !important;
          border-top-color: rgb(170 170 170)  !important;
          }


    /* Optional: Make active tab title bold for easy identification. This style can be deleted. */
    .docs-sheet-active-tab {
            font-weight: 700 !important;

          }



    `);
```